# The correct way to display Pods 2.0 items using PHP code in a Pods template

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I'm almost tearing my hair off! I believe you are supposed to be able to use PHP, javacript etc other than HTML in PODS 2.0 template right? If so why is it that I get my items to display in a pods template using magic tags but I cannot echo stuff out using PHP code?

I set up a Pods template to display my stuff using the code below:

```
<h5><a href="{@permalink}">{@post_title}</a></h5>
<div>
<?php 
$mypod = pods( 'post' );
echo $mypod->field( 'post_title' ); 
?>
</div>
```

It outputs the **post_title** in a heading (h5) as expected but nothing shows u in the div. What am I doing wrong. Let me mention that I am not using a Pod's page but I am using a the Pod's list widget to display this in my WP sidebar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't giving pods() the ID of the post you want to use. But your main issue is that you don't need to setup a new pods() object at all, you just need to use this:

```
<?php echo $obj->display( 'post_title' ); ?>
```

$obj references the current Pods object used, when in a template.

Also, I'm using display here, because it will then run any filters that the_title() would normally run, when in Pods.

Comment: Thought I might not need to set up a new pods object too but I couldn't figure out how to reference my Pod otherwise. Worked! Thanks a lot Scott.

Comment: afaik in more recent versions you cannot use PHP anymore in templates

Comment: We deprecated PHP in templates, we're moving towards Twig templating which will allow much more versatile templating processes. As far as templates, we recommend using `[pods view="your-template.php"]` shortcode so it loads `your-template.php` from your theme (or child theme) which holds the PHP there. It's easier to manage and less problematic for allowing PHP eval() to run within templates.